# Discord.JS - How to set a field in an embed conditionally?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a simple embed in discord. How do I then add a field only if a boolean value is true? Example pseudocode:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Example Embed')
    //conditional bits
    .setConditionalField(booleanValue, 'Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)

    //OR:
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()//setting stuff here;

//later on
if(someStuff){
    embed.AddField(values);
}
```

I have tried the `embed.SomeFunction` path but, like many other ways I have tried, it throws `TypeError: fields.flat is not a function`

I believe the error occurs when I attempt to send the embed, however I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update to nodejs 12. That will fix your issue, nothing wrong with your code.